# Rails DELETE route not working properly / not calling the controller function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using React and Rails API. To make a request from React I am using Axios library and the code looks like this:

```js
const _deleteIssue = () => {
        axios.delete(`${ROOT_API}/v1/issue/delete/${props.issue.id}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
            }
        }).then(res => {
            props.updateProjectData()
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

In order to handle this request I have set up a route for it which looks like this:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :base_api do
    # other routes
    post 'issues/create', to: 'issues#create'
    delete 'issue/delete/:issue_id', to: 'issues#delete_issue'
  end

  namespace :v1 do
    concerns :base_api
  end
end
```

As you can see from the code snippet above, the route is set to call `delete_issue` function inside of the `issues` controller. I have created that function and it looks like this:

```rb
class V1::IssuesController < ApplicationController

    # other functions

    def delete_issue     
        Issue.find_by(id: params[:issue_id]).delete
        render json: {}, status: 200
    end
end
```

I am justing trying to `find` the issue with an id that is passed as params from Axios delete request.

It is supposed to delete it and return nothing with a status code of 200. What happens instead is that in my "Network" tab inside of developer tools in my browser(Firefox) shows the `200 OK` request with the `OPTIONS` method. There is no `DELETE` method being sent or anything.

I even tried to comment out the `delete_issue` function from `IssuesController` and there was not 404 routing error. The result was the same. I can't find out what is wrong with it even though it is probably a pretty obvious error which I can't see.

Note that I am using Rails 6.

Comment: How are you calling the `_deleteIssue` method in your application?

Comment: what is the console saying (i.e. the rails server output)?

Comment: @Redline I am using `onClick` on `Tooltip` from Material UI like this `<Tooltip onClick={_deleteIssue} title="Delete issue" style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>`

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Nothing... I just noticed that now... Weird

Comment: Try changing you onclick handler to `onClick={() => _deleteIssue()}`. It's a long shot, but I can't do much without access to a reproducible example.

Comment: @Redline thanks for the tip but I don't think that is the problem since the request is "kinda" being sent because I can see it in the network tab of dev tools, which means the function is actually run, but I'll try it

Comment: @crodev Ok, if the function is being run then the problem must be with the axios request. What is the ${ROOT_API} variable assigned to?

Comment: @Redline it's just this line `export const ROOT_API = "http://localhost:3000"` which I imported, works on every other request

Comment: @crodev Huh, that's really weird. Any chance you could share a github repo, or a slimmed down example? Otherwise, I can't do much

Comment: Sure, I'll make the repo public since it's pretty much a project for my portfolio

Comment: So here is link for the fron-end repo: https://github.com/LukaPavicic/boardee_react, and here is link for the backend repo: https://github.com/LukaPavicic/boardee

Comment: If it helps you in any way it is a Jira clone that I am building. And it really bugs me because I'm sure it's a simple error which I can't find.

Comment: @Redline And I forgot to tag you, don't know if you got notifications for the comments above.

Comment: @crodev After running it locally, I think I have the answer. It seems you did not configure rack-cors in your rails app. After allowing the react app origin in the `cors.rb` file everything is working fine, and the delete request is going to the rails app.

Comment: @Redline That's it, thanks a lot! How did I forget about cors man. You can write an answer if you want so I can accept it.

Comment: @crodev No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you did not configure rack-cors. Simply add this to your `cors.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3001' # or you react app domain

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```